# Why don't I see details of UIKit exception in XCode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsexception

I am working on UITableView and `beginUpdates`,`endupdates`. Probably some rows or sections or not in sync with dataSource. That is why I get an exception like below:

`*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UITableView.m:1368`

Normally, It also has to print additional details about this specific exception. It was doing so.. I have enabled every debug symbol and disabled stripping everywhere.

What am I missing here? How can I reactivate that hidden exception detail?